# @Mockbean with @Qualifer throws during the Junit test run

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, repository, spring-boot-test

i am writing the junits for the below class,

```
@Repository
public class IncidentRepository {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("mysqlJdbcTemplate")
    private JdbcTemplate mysqlJdbcTemplate;


    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("oracleJdbcTemplate")
    private JdbcTemplate oracleJdbcTemplate;

    private String tableName = "BSC_INCIDENT_STG_3";


    public String getTableName() {
        return tableName;
    }

    public List<Incident> listAll() {
        String cprSql = "SELECT 1 FROM DUAL";
        return oracleJdbcTemplate.query(cprSql, new IncidentMapper());

    }
}
```

and the Junit class i am working on is this,

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = CommonConfig.class)
public class IncidentRepositoryTest {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    @InjectMocks
    IncidentRepository incidentRepository;

    @Qualifier("mysqlJdbcTemplate")
    private JdbcTemplate mysqlJdbcTemplate;

    @Qualifier("oracleJdbcTemplate")
    private JdbcTemplate oracleJdbcTemplate;

    @MockBean
    private Incident incident;

@MockBean
    private IncidentMapper incidentMapper;

    private String deleteSqlQuery = "DELETE FROM ";

    String cprSql = "SELECT 1 FROM DUAL";

    List<Incident> incidentList = new ArrayList<Incident>();

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        //All Initializations goes here.
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);     
        mysqlJdbcTemplate = Mockito.mock(JdbcTemplate.class);
        oracleJdbcTemplate = Mockito.mock(JdbcTemplate.class);

        incident.setIncidentNumber("incidentNumber");
        incident.setApplicationId("J12342");
        incident.setCategory("O12987");
        incident.setOpenTime("ApplicationName");
        incident.setSeverityCode("OwningLob");
        incident.setAssignment("reportingCIOLOB");
        incident.setStatus("reportingCTOGroup");
        incident.setCloseTime("rto");
        incident.setStatus("status");
        incident.setElapsedTime("assetName");
        incident.setResolutionCode("environment");
        incident.setType("invNo");
        incident.setOpenGroup("osiStatus");
        incident.setResolvedGroup("measuredID");
        incident.setResolvedTime("policyID");
        incident.setUserPriority("policyName");
        incident.setJpAcctLob("lastBreakDate");
        incident.setJpAcctAppRto("lastClearedDate");
        incident.setJpImpact("osiStatus");
        incident.setJpImpactDurationMin("measuredID");
        incident.setJpExternalId("policyID");
        incident.setJpExternalSystem("policyName");
        incident.setJpConfigItem("lastBreakDate");
        incident.setJpMasterHost("lastClearedDate");
        incident.setJpSite("osiStatus");
        incident.setJpAppserviceName("measuredID");
        incident.setJpAppserviceId("policyID");
        incident.setJpVerumidentifier("policyName");

        incidentList.add(incident);

    }

    @Test
    public void testListAll() throws Exception {

when(oracleJdbcTemplate.query(cprSql,incidentMapper)).thenReturn(incidentList);
        incidentRepository.listAll();       
    }
}
```

The problem now is that mysqlJdbcTemplate object is always null in the IncidentRepository class even when i mocked it.

I dont want to you @Autowired annotation .i just want to mock the objects.

Can someone please help ?

Comment: You aren't mocking anything. You only have `@Qualifier` on the field. Also when you are mocking everything what is the point of using a Spring Boot based test at all?

Comment: @M.Deinum He is mocking them within the `setUp()` method, but his code is indeed quite confusing since it combines some parts of running a Spring boot based test and some parts of a Mockito/plain JUnit test.

Comment: For Spring Boot he isn't mocking them. Hence from that POV no mocking. He is basically bypassing everything...

Comment: sorry for typos...

Comment: i solved it by setting up the qualifer using whitebox!!.. Whitebox.setInternalState(incidentRepository, "mysqlJdbcTemplate", mysqlJdbcTemplate);

Comment: You are making things overly complex. Remove all the spring boot stuf. Use the `MockitoJUnitRunner` to run your test and place `@Mock` annotations on the fields requiring to be mocked and simply run your test. You are trying to work around the frameworks and even throwing more frameworks at it to solve something that shouldn't need solving in the first place.